How to add query parameters into Iframe
I have following code which fetch firstname from localStorage and I am using reactjs:
if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
    if (
      localStorage.isLoggedIn === true ||
      localStorage.isLoggedIn === "true"
    ) {
      let firstname = localStorage.getItem("firstName");

      let firstNameElements = document.getElementsByName("firstname");
      if (firstNameElements && firstNameElements[0]) {
        firstNameElements[0].value = firstname;
      }

    }
  }
  return true;

And the following is an Iframe:
<IframeWrapper src={"https://go.offer.domain.com/l/1021843/2023-09-14/abcd?first_name=abc"} />

I am facing issue to add parameters in above link dynamically. If I add firstname = abc it adds abc into first name field but how can I add firstname dynamically as I have also shared above syntax use to fetch firstname from localStorage?

Your question is unclear. you are writing pure js in react (no problem if you do but I think there are better ways to handle this)? can you provide more context and code for the question

I have Iframe link which I shared in my question which generate form and in form I have firstname, lastname and email which I want to pre-fill base on login user. I can get user credentials from localStorage but after that I need to pass query paramters into an Iframe and which I am unable to to how I can pass those query paramters into an Iframe.

What you’re trying to do won’t work. To pass data in to the iframe you need to use the postMessage API.
document
  .getElementByTagName(‘iframe’)[0]
  .postMessage({ firstName, lastName }, ‘*’)

Then in the iframe.
window.addEventListener(‘message’, 
  ({ data }) => console.log(data)
)

